# Php and Drupal: how do I hide/display my link when needed using php within Drupal?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, drupal-7

Perhaps it is easier if I ask the question this way - Using the coding snippet below, how would I write the code to display the "Change" link only when the value in status is "A"?

I think i'm making this harder than it has to be, but the use of both drupal module structure and php are throwing me, since i am just learning module development.

The link showing in the array below appears at the end of each of my rows.  I only want it to appear when the status equals "A".

Because this link is within this array, i can't figure out how and where to implement it.  I just want an [if statement] like this:

```
if (drupal_render($form['status'][$key]['status']) == 'A',)
echo l(t('Change'), 'rooms/avail_room/' . $key . '/' . arg(1), array('attributes' => array('class' => 'room-stat-avail'))),
else{
echo "";
}
```

so when the html table is displayed, the '**Change**' link will only appear in the last column when the value of status is "A"

Can't believe I got the module working, but can't turn this link on/off as i want.  See code snippet below:

```
function team_room_available_form($form) {
    $output = "No space available.";

  if ($form['roomid']) {
    foreach (element_children($form['roomid']) as $key) {
      $rows[] = array(
        'data' => array(
          drupal_render($form[''][$key]),
          drupal_render($form['room_title'][$key]),
          drupal_render($form['username'][$key]),
          drupal_render($form['status'][$key]['status']),
          l(t('Change'), 'rooms/avail_room/' . $key . '/' . arg(1), array('attributes' => array('class' => 'room-stat-avail'))),
        ),
        'class' => $form['status'][$key]['#value'],
      );
    }
```

Comment: In your code above you test for equality using `= 'A'`, but it should be `== 'A'`. As your code is written now, you are using an assignment rather than a comparison.

Comment: Hi Ryan - thanks for your response and I'm sorry, I was just just using example coding for the if/then statement.  I will clean that up, but my issue is really how do i check the status outside of the array that is holding the values?

Comment: Using drupal at all makes it harder than it has to be. what does this actually output: `drupal_render($form['status'][$key]['status'])`

Comment: it will output a letter, either and A or U.  On click of the link, the value can be changed.  But I only want the link to appear when the value is 'A'.

Comment: And you are correct, because I am a bit stuck in the array, I can't just stick the if statement in just above the link line.

Comment: Your statement is ambiguous - it "will" is presumptuous. Unless you mean it DOES, in which case it is definitive. If you remove the drupal_render part as Patrick suggests, you should just be left with "A" or "U". Also, your echo l() statement in that condition is ending with a comma, not a semi colon as it should. Could be a basic paste error when asking this question? If not, you're probably encountering a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really call drupal_render() on every element of your array.

drupal_render is a theming function to be applied on a renderable array. Check the drupal docs on drupal.org ... [Render Arrays in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/930760)

Practically this means that you should apply your logic within your module before creating your renderable array. Practically your renderable array is just a bunch of values that follows Drupal theming structure.

When you create your array, your logic is just typical PHP. With Drupal you should really try the devel module. It will help you to output your results and help you debug your code.